# Encoding password field for HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: php, http, curl, encoding, basic-authentication

I using PHP cURL to communicate with a Rest API. Most of the functionality is carried out using X-Ephemeral-Tokens, but unfortunately they don't allow delete permissions to be given through these, so I am having to implement a function to delete through HTTP Basic Authentication.

The trouble I'm having is that the password for the testing account is a random string, including multiple special characters (double quotation marks being some of them). I got the request working using the normal cURL binary by surrounding the `username:password` combination in single quotes (i.e. `'`) but I'm not sure how to convert this to PHP. The relevant snippet is below.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json",
                                              "Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $uname . ":" . $pass);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloud.ravellosystems.com/api/v1/applications/" . $appid);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

I've tried various combinations of quotation marks and URL encoding but I still get a response code which indicates the authentication isn't working right.

This is and exmaple HTTP request based on what the API documentation shows for using normal cURL (amended slightly)

```
curl -v -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --user ravello@ravello.com:password https://cloud.ravellosystems.com/api/v1/applications/414244
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok so if anyone else has this issue, I've found a solution.

Basically you can see in my code above that I was trying to use the cURL PHP methods to set options for `CURLOPT_USERPWD` and `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`. However somewhere in this the special characters in the password were causing issues with the parsing and I think only a section of it was actually being taken by the server.

However, all that these options do basically is set an HTTP header, as can be seen in @mpyw screenshots. This is the `Authorization` header, which is in the format below:

```
`Authorization: Basic [base64 encoded username:password]`
```

So I got rid of these options and did it manually, by base64 encoding my `username:password` string myself and then adding a header.

```
$auth = base64_encode($uname . ":" . $pass);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic $auth",
                                              "Accept: application/json",
                                              "Content-Type: application/json"));
```

Now it all works fine! Thanks to the guys who posted answers - both of you contributed to me coming up with the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I compared two ways, enabling verbose outputs.

[image]
[image]

Emitted headers are the same, except that the PHP does not contain `User-Agent` header. Does the API require `User-Agent` header?

---

Edit

### Password that contains `'`

[image]
[image]

### Password that contains `"`

[image]
[image]

Comment: No the API doesn't need a User Agent. The examples you've put don't seem to address the issue of special characters in the password (or username) though, or are you saying that shouldn't be a problem and I should maybe look for other causes?

Comment: Actually I had forgot using special chars, but probably it doesn't matter.

Comment: Are the libcurl versions those used by both PHP and commandline curl client the same?

Comment: It requires a curl version of 7.10.5 or above, but during the installation I installed curl using apt on Ubuntu so it should be the latest stable version.

Comment: Hmmm not sure why your edit above was working fine with the special characters. Mine definitely wasn't, but the password was a completely random string and had lots of different ones so maybe the issue was more than just the quotation marks. Ended up getting it working, posted the solution below. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to base64_encode the username and password.  Try this:

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, base64_encode($uname . ":" . $pass));`

Comment: You were along the right lines, but you have to work this directly into a header instead of using the USERPWD option. Posted my solution as an answer below